# No convenient overload for std::for_each for whole range?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Why is there no overload for std::for_each, or any other std::algorithm functions of similar form like:

```cpp
template<class Container, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(Container c, UnaryFunction f);
```

that would basically just do:

```cpp
template<class Contianer, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(Container c, UnaryFunction f){
    return std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), f);
}
```

It seems to me that I am often using these types of functions on the entire range of a container, and it seems inconvenient, especially with long container names, to type:

```cpp
std::for_each(myLongContainerNameThatIsLong.begin(), myLongContainerNameThatIsLong.end(), f);
```

Is there any detail I'm missing that prevents this, or some mechanism to get the signature I want?

Comment: What's wrong with `for (auto& elem: myLongContainer) { f(elem); }` ?

Comment: @bloody Nothing is wrong with that. But there are lots of functions in std::algorithm that have a similar signature, like sort, or find_if. for_each isn't particularly useful IMO but was probably added for consistency or as a primative for std::algorithm.

Comment: Right, I missed your point about other *std* algorithms, focused on the very example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no fundamental reason you can't do that, and in fact from C++20, you can do exactly that with [std::ranges::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/for_each):

```
std::ranges::for_each(myLongContainerNameThatIsLong, f);
```

Comment: C++20 seems like its going to be a cool release, can't wait.

Comment: @ShaneMurphy For sure. I've been on the edge of my seat for a while :)

Comment: To be fair, the ranges proposal leverages language features that didn't exist in C++ before C++17.   Before that, introducing such a capability would have been challenging or involving significant technical trade-offs.

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure that's true. There are libraries that achieve the same functionality pre-C++20 as well. Yes, features such as Concepts make it much easier to implement ranges, but I'm not sure they're strictly necessary.

Comment: @Peter Oops, I see you said pre-C++17. What are the features added in C++17 that are necessary to allow ranges to work?

Comment: @cigien - There are discussions around about how the C++20 ranges proposal would have been difficult or prohibitive without leveraging concepts.   While there was an earlier version of concepts (proposed and abandoned for C++11, from memory), concepts in its current form (described by some as a "lite" version of the previous concepts proposal) wasn't proposed before C++17.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.

Comment: Personally I'm waiting for C++123. The one with the telepathic compiler that generates code that does what you want and not what you told it to do.